# Wistia Video getting error: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()

Tags: javascript, wistia

For some reason our bugsnag reported some issue on our webpages that has `wistia video` embedded.

We have simple set up as below:

```
<script src="https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/test-video-link.jsonp" async></script>
<script src="https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>

<span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_xxxxxxxxx popover=true popoverAnimateThumbnail=true" style="display:block;height:50px;position:relative;width:60px">&nbsp;</span>
```

Bugsnag Error Details:

```
The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()

Promise:

rejection reason
{
  "[object DOMException]": {
    "name": "AbortError",
    "message": "The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause(). https : //goo . gl/test-video-link",
    "code": 20
  }
}
```